# Windows Admin Center (WAC) + Powershell

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, powershell, script

so I'm using a PowerShell script which runs .exe installation,
both the script and the .exe file located in the same network folder,
when I run the script directly from the pc it runs well,
but when I'm using WAC's PowerShell console i get an error:

> The term '\\it\installation\PMPAgent\PMP_Agent.exe' is not
> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
> verify that the path  is correct and try again.
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\it\installati...armel_Agent.exe:String) [],
> CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

what can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `PMP_Agent.exe` file is not located in the right place for WAC to see it. Try out some of the following:

- Use `Get-Location` in the console to figure out WAC's current directory
- Use `Test-Path \\server\share\path\to\PMP_Agent.exe` to determine if WAC can actually view the file

The path to the .exe must be valid from the WAC server, not just on your local PC. `'\it\installation\PMPAgent\PMP_Agent.exe'` is generally a local path, so make sure this is correct.